# R programming function without ()

Tags: r, function, interactive

So, I Have the following very simple map.r file.

I'm trying to have the user type "click" in interactive mode and then have the function .

Since it's a function, the user has to type "click()" how can I make it so that they only have to the word (w/o parentheses), and then have that function do something with the img.

So the user types:

> mydist("image.pnm")
>
> click

//And then the function click does what it's supposed to

```
mydist <- function(mapfile) {

    img <- read.pnm(mapfile)

    plot(img)
}

click <- function() {

    //Prompt user to click on img
}
```

Comment: More details would help.  What are you trying to do?  Why not just put `click()` in the `mydist` function?  There's at least one way to do what you're asking for, but the use case seems odd, at least with the way it's described so far.  More details would help provide answers tailored to your situation.

Comment: In a comment below, @MarkKennedy wrote: I wanted a command list type of functionality, here. click would be read in somehow like readline() and then the .r does something. etc etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you give it a class of its own and a print method which echoes that message you can achieve your goal.

```
  print.click <- function(x, ...){
    #
    # could do something here
    # the <something> could be a plot or calculation
    plot(1:10, 10:1, type="l")
   cat("Your click message here\n perhaps \n Downward line plotted!")
     invisible(x)
 }
 click <- "click"
 class(click) <- "click"


 click
# Your click message here
# perhaps 
# Downward line plotted!
```

Even if you wanted to "encapsulate" the class definition in the object itself as Aaron demonstrated, you would not be limited to printing a message. You could do something like this:

```
print.click <- function(x, ...) {plot(1:10, 10:1, type="l")
   cat("prompt user to click on img...\n")
```

If you wanted to call `locator`, you could extend the interactivity with the user.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the 'proper' way to do it.  This is an example from my .Rprofile file.

```
invisible(makeActiveBinding("newq", function(...){quartz();par(cex=.75); cat("OK\n")}, .GlobalEnv))
```

The function `makeActiveBinding` does some sort of magic so the complete function gets called w/o need for any parentheses.

Comment: This is the more compact way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do what you've asked for.  However, there may be a better way to do what you're trying to do.

```
click <- structure(1, class="click")
print.click <- function(x, ...) {
  cat("prompt user to click on img...\n")
}
```

Then

```
> click
prompt user to click on img...
```

Comment: I wanted a command list type of functionality, here. click would be read in somehow like readline() and then the .r does something. etc etc

Comment: Aaron's approach is a bit more compact than mine (and would override mine if they were in the same session), but they both allow you to attach any set of plotting or other commands to the execution of the code.

Comment: Thanks, @DWin.  Yours has better commentary, though.  Feel free to add this way of defining `click` to yours; if you want to do that I'll probably delete this answer; it's mostly superfluous already.

Comment: Thanks for permission, but I liked it so much I already did. I'll upvote, too.

Comment: @DWin, I meant the `structure` line; otherwise they're the same, yes?  I don't actually know what you mean by "encapsulate the class definition in the object."

Comment: I just meant not using `class<-` and instead using `structure`. Looks cleaner.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  I think it looks cleaner too, though perhaps less pedagogically clear.

Answer (score 1):

I could be totally confused as to what you want to do, but I think something like below may answer your query. It can be expanded upon by adding other 'else-if' options and other custom functions to be run as a result of whatever the user types.

```
customfunction <- function() {
print(1:10)
}

mydist <- function(mapfile) {

   img <- read.pnm(mapfile)
   plot(img)

ANSWER <- readline("")

# customfunction() will be run (printing 1:10) as soon as 
# the user types "click" and hits enter

if (ANSWER=="click") customfunction()

}
```

Comment: +1 From what the OP has said, this sounds like what I'd do; one could even print a little menu for the user to choose what they want to do.