# iterate interactively many plots to different files

Tags: r, loops, plot

I have the need to build a function that will plot multiple pdfs, read them in, combine the results (different sized pdfs), save the combined file and delete the initial files.  I'm getting hung up on the initial part of interactively plotting multiple plots to external pdfs.  The problem is I need a way of pausing in the `for` loop, waiting for the plot and then moving on after receiving the plot.  I thought `readLines` was the way to go (and it may be) but this did not work (i.e. no plot was produced).

How can I make R pause between `pdf` take the plot, move onto `dev.off` and reiterate through the process again?  The desired outcome is to have three files in the wd called `file1.pdf`, `file2.pdf` and `file3.pdf`.  Again, after running the loop/`lapply`, this process will be interactive.

This is a MWE of the problem:

```
widths <- c(10, 9, 8)
heights <- c(11, 9, 7)
file <- "foo.pdf"
lapply(1:3, function(i) {  #will askfor/take 3 plots interactively
    qo <- gsub(".pdf", paste0(i, ".pdf"), file, fixed = TRUE)
    cat("plot now...")
    pdf(file=qo, width = widths[i], height = heights[i])
#pause command here
    dev.off()
})

#the interactive part
plot(1:10)
plot(1:13)
plot(1:15)
```

**EDIT 1** *Related question:* [Determine ghostscript version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366406/determine-ghostscript-version)

**EDIT 2** Here's a link to the package I used this information to create [-click here-](https://github.com/trinker/plotflow)

Comment: If I can understand why you want to do this, I might be more motivated to try and think of a solution...

Comment: @Andrie I want to create a larger function based on [(LINK)](http://trinkerrstuff.wordpress.com/2012/10/08/splitting-and-combining-r-pdf-visuals/#comment-133) that will enable me to output a single file of various sized plots.  This will save time in the workflow.  I plan on making this into a `github` only package and writing a blog post about it on RBloggers to share as I think this may be useful to others as well.

Comment: @TylerRinker - do you mean `readline` in your question, not `readLines` which is totally different? Could you do something using this sort of logic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130469/r-programming-function-without

Comment: @thelatemail I meant `readLines`.  The idea is to get the loop to stop so it can receive the plot and then move on...stop again receive...move one...  I'm looking at the link but am not able to figure out how to use this information.

Comment: `scan("", what = "character", quiet=TRUE)`?

Comment: Could you wait for the file size of your file to be greater than zero and not changing? You could implement a while loop to wait for the file to be written. Once that's done, you could break out of the loop and carry on.

Comment: @redmode I tried what I think you mean and it ends with empty files.

Comment: @Roman this may be viable but is beyond my current understanding of R coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it as simple as this?

```
for(i in 1:3){
  cat(i, "\n")
  cat("plot now...")
  readLines(n=1)
}
```

---

This stops to read a single line from `stdin`, i.e. the console. Press Enter to carry on.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I tried what I think you meant and it ends with empty files.  Maybe I have not implemented it correctly (see the question for the attempted implementation).

Comment: This worked the best with some modification because it accepts lines with spaces.  Here's a link to the github of the package in progress [-click here-](https://github.com/trinker/plotflow).  It's a start.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
widths <- c(10, 9, 8)
heights <- c(11, 9, 7)
file <- "foo.pdf"
lapply(1:3, function(i) {
    qo <- gsub(".pdf", paste0(i, ".pdf"), file, fixed = TRUE)
    pdf(file=qo, width = widths[i], height = heights[i])
    # Reads string interactively
    input <- scan("", what = "character", nmax=1, quiet=TRUE)
    # Executes `input` as a command (possibly, needs extra check)
    eval(parse(text=input))
    dev.off()
})
```

This results in three files: `foo1.pdf`, `foo2.pdf` and `foo3.pdf` with plots produced using commands you typed interactively.

Comment: I believe that's it; as long as the plot command is a on single line.

Comment: You can remove `nmax=1` for multiple lines.

Comment: I used this to create the solution but `readLines` was more appropriate to deal with spaces.